openresty lua-resty-core how set_current_peer works?
I'm trying to setup active-standby failover on Jenkins with Openresty. I have a setup with two Jenkins, and I want to switch between them when one is down, however I'm always getting error "no upstream found":
2024/10/07 20:38:30 [error] 19681#19681: *42 [lua] conter.lua:44: switch_to_backup(): Failed to switch to backup server: no upstream found, context: ngx.timer, client: 192.168.141.223, server: 0.0.0.0:443

I followed up this guide when tried to configure
https://kura.gg/2020/08/09/retrying-dynamically-configured-upstreams-with-openresty/
Openresty config - i've added upstream servers in init_by_lua_block and all logic in balancer_by_lua_file:
http {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    log_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conter.lua;

    lua_package_path ";;/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/?.lua;";
    lua_max_running_timers 1024;
    lua_shared_dict healthcheck 1m;
    lua_shared_dict log_dict 5M;
    lua_shared_dict my_shared_dict 10m;

    lua_socket_log_errors on;

    init_by_lua_block {
        upstream_servers = {
            "192.168.141.218:8080",
            "192.168.141.204:8080",
        }
    }

    upstream jenkins-uat {
        server 192.168.141.218:8080;
        balancer_by_lua_file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/conter.lua;
        keepalive 32;
    }

    server {
        listen            80 default_server;
        server_name     192.168.141.218;
        location / {
            return 301 https://192.168.141.218$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen                443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate       /etc/ssl/private/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem;
        server_name     192.168.141.218;

        access_log      /var/log/jenkins-uat.access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/jenkins-uat.error.log;

        ignore_invalid_headers off;

        location / {

            sendfile off;
            proxy_pass         http://jenkins-uat;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
            add_header X-Upstream $upstream_addr always;

            client_max_body_size       100m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      90;
            proxy_send_timeout         90;
            proxy_read_timeout         90;
            proxy_buffering            off;
            proxy_request_buffering    off;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
        }
    }
}

Lua file with failover logic, error in switch_to_backup() function
-- Counter and flags initialization
if not shared_dict:get("5xx_errors_10s") then
    shared_dict:set("5xx_errors_10s", 0)
end
if not shared_dict:get("5xx_errors_60s") then
    shared_dict:set("5xx_errors_60s", 0)
end
if not shared_dict:get("primary_server_down") then
    shared_dict:set("primary_server_down", false)
end

-- Increment 5xx errors
local function increment_5xx_errors()
    shared_dict:incr("5xx_errors_10s", 1)
    shared_dict:incr("5xx_errors_60s", 1)
end

-- Send POST request
local function send_post_request(url)
    local httpc = http.new()
    local res, err = httpc:request_uri(url, {
        method = "POST",
        headers = {
            ["Authorization"] = "Basic YWRtaW46MTE5MTBhMTQyZThlNjY3NjcyMTllYjc0MzhjZmE3MGUwNg==",
        },
        ssl_verify = false
    })
    if not res then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Failed to send POST request: ", err)
        return nil, err
    end
    return res
end

-- Switch traffic on reserve Jenkins server, error happens here
local function switch_to_backup()
    local balancer = require "ngx.balancer"
    local server = upstream_servers[1]
    local ok, err = balancer.set_current_peer(server)
    if not ok then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Failed to switch to backup server: ", err)
    else
        shared_dict:set("primary_server_down", true)
    end
end

-- Switch back on main Jenkins server
local function switch_to_primary()
    local balancer = require "ngx.balancer"
    local ok, err = balancer.set_current_peer("192.168.141.218", 8080)
    if not ok then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Failed to switch to primary server: ", err)
    else
        shared_dict:set("primary_server_down", false)
    end
end

-- 5xx error counter
local function count_5xx_errors()
    local status = ngx.status
    if status >= 500 and status < 600 then
        increment_5xx_errors()
    end
end

-- Check thresholds set to switch between servers
local function check_thresholds()
    if shared_dict:get("primary_server_down") then
        return
    end

    local errors_10s = shared_dict:get("5xx_errors_10s")
    local errors_60s = shared_dict:get("5xx_errors_60s")

    if errors_10s > 1 then
        send_post_request("http://192.168.141.204:8080/reload")
    end
    if errors_60s > 10 then
        send_post_request("http://192.168.141.204:8080/cancelQuietDown")
        switch_to_backup()
    end
end

-- Check main server status
local function check_primary_server()
    if not shared_dict:get("primary_server_down") then
        return
    end

    local httpc = http.new()
    local res, err = httpc:request_uri("http://192.168.141.218:8080/", {
        method = "GET",
        ssl_verify = false
    })
    if res and res.status < 500 then
        send_post_request("http://192.168.141.204:8080/quietDown")
        switch_to_primary()
    end
end

-- Reset counters
local function reset_5xx_errors()
    shared_dict:set("5xx_errors_10s", 0)
    shared_dict:set("5xx_errors_60s", 0)
end

-- function start
count_5xx_errors()

-- Set timers
ngx.timer.every(10, function()
    check_thresholds()
    reset_5xx_errors()
end)

ngx.timer.every(60, function()
    check_thresholds()
    reset_5xx_errors()
end)

-- Timer to check main server
ngx.timer.every(30, function()
    check_primary_server()
end)

